# How might one fly from KRYN to SDRS in a de Hallivand DHC-6 Twin Otter?

Tags: fuel, refueling, long-haul

First of all, this is not a flight I'm attempting myself; it's for a writing project. I myself have absolutely no knowledge at all of flight. The plane would depart from Ryan Airfield, Arizona (ICAO: KRYN) and land at Resende Airfield (SDRS). As the de Havilland DHC-6 has a range of only 886.7 miles, I assume a great deal of refueling is required. I have no knowledge of flight, so the logistics of a flight this length, (about 5,900 miles), in a light aircraft, are completely alien to me. Importantly, the passengers on the flight (4) do not have passports, but must still be able to enter the country. I’m guessing this means they’d land at a small airport/airfield. Assume the pilot has connections that allow his passengers to bypass any security at the small/private airport. The most important information would be: how long it would take, where/when they’d need to stop on the way, and where could the final destination be.

Your help is greatly, greatly appreciated! :)

Also, assume the situation is urgent and the pilot is a risk taker. He wants to get his passengers there quickly as possible.

Comment: Skipping customs is rather the hard part here. Even many small airports do have custom officials and after crossing border, you are required by law to land at airport that does have one. But you don't want to do that, which means choosing untowered strips and generally avoiding contact with authorities altogether. Contacts most likely to help are in drug cartels that can tell you where you can bribe the authorities and how to avoid the ones that may be less corruptible.

Comment: … you also have to make sure there will be some *jet* fuel waiting for you on the small airports you use as DHC-6 is a turbine aircraft, but most traffic in the small fields is piston aircraft that use avgas.

Comment: My pilot is a tricky guy. Due to money, connections (often illegal), and extensive beforehand planning, he'll know the who, what, when, etc. of how to get them through with little to no incident. Perhaps a bad contact could present difficulties, or some other mishap could occur on the pilot's behalf. Thanks for the info, it was very helpful!

Comment: You can add some hurried departure when some nosey cops find about them anyway, followed by flying low above the trees to avoid appearing on any ATC's radar and then perhaps searching for some drug lord's strip hidden in the middle of the jungle…

Comment: Will they need to fly below/around radar like drug smugglers do, which will drastically reduce range and require a circuitous route? Or is the pilot going to fly normally and just rely on his connections to skip customs at the end?

Comment: As time is rather important, I'm guessing he'll just rely on his connections and hope for the best. As I said, he's reckless, so that probably fits best anyway. Thanks again for the suggestions, everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend that you go to https://skyvector.com/ and create a flight plan.  It isn't too difficult, just click on "Flight Plan" in the top left corner and you should be able to figure out the rest.

You obviously have some familiarity with ICAO airport identifiers, simply look for airports along the way that will keep you under a 886.7 NM leg length, and enter them one by one to build your route.  I would use a cruising speed of around 150KIAS based on a quick Google search of Twin Otter performance.  The website will calculate the times for each leg based on this airspeed.

As far as researching suitable airfields that can provide fuel and other services, that will take quite a bit of additional work.  I don't have a handy reference for you, but you could start by searching for World or Latin American Airport Directories.  I wouldn't expect anyone here to do all that work for you and post it as an answer.  If you have any detailed questions as you go don't be afraid to ask.

Regarding your questions about avoiding immigration authorities, that's up to your fertile imagination to come up with fictional scenarios.  There is no aviation specific way to answer this, and most people would be hesitant to recommend methods to circumvent the law.

Comment: If the OP wants more "realism", they can't just pick waypoints 886 NM apart. There are 30 minute (day VFR) and 45 minute (night VFR) reserve requirements. I'd assume they are not flying IFR if they are trying to skip customs. They would also need to take into account winds (head wind), so that they don't run out of fuel getting to an airport.

Comment: Good points, but you'll note I said "under 886"...  Also, presuming this is for a work of fiction, the situation is urgent, the flight will be through Latin America, and the pilot is a risk taker I didn't feel it was necessary to educate the author on FAA fuel reserve requirements for IFR vs VFR.

Comment: Also, the quoted range is for max cruise power and including IFR reserves, and can usually be extended somewhat by flying slower. Plus, if the author needs to make the stops a bit closer or further to get locations that suit the story, they can write in head- or tailwinds, respectively.